# Prevent indexing a domain in search engines like Google and Bing

Tags: .htaccess, search-engine, robots.txt

I have a domain (e.g. domain.com) which is public for all users and I have a secret sub-domain (e.g. site1.secretdomain.com) of a general domain (here secretdomain.com) just for admins of the site.

I don't want Google or other Search Engines index either the secret domain or its subdomains. Do you have any idea for that? I think robots.txt doesn't work because it makes changes for all domains.

Answer (score 0):

A not so fool-proof solution is to remove, or issue a NO-Follow directive to  any references to the subdomain-pages along with other necessary changes in robots.txt.

Another little more expensive, but more concrete but on a pragmatic note, would be to look into CAPTCHA or [Google's ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html).

On a more theoretical note, Without much research, I guess a typical approach to the problem would be to serve a unique Cryptographic/Some form of Challenge (Computationally Expensive Problem) upon a request to and use the solution to validate a session from the user. 
Even the most advanced Crawlers work with a limited Javascript execution budget; and will decide to move on to other pages once exhausted. FInd a suitable challenge, Optimize the page design to factor in for a load delay, and you have a subdomain open to all humans but not bots.